# iOS universal link with url path containing "#!"

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, hashbang, aasa

My iOS app has to support a universal link to a page something like

https://example.com/#!/game/home

And I am having difficulties in getting this to work. I have created an AASA file like

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "ASDF35SDF.ios.mybundle.com",
            "components": [{
                "/": "/#!/courses/*/home"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I also tried with wildcards instead of directly adding "#!" in the AASA file.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "ASDF35SDF.ios.mybundle.com",
            "components": [{
                "/": "/*/courses/*/home"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Both didn't work. I have verified that my AASA file is correctly read (server logs). I have other paths without "#!" in the AASA file which are working correctly (thus making sure my AASA file is read correctly).

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1**

Tried with new fragment components, but no luck there either

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "ASDF35SDF.ios.mybundle.com",
            "components": [{
                "#": "!/courses/*/home"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything after # is not in the path. It is the fragment. See [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/supporting-associated-domains). You will have something like `"#":"!/courses/*/home"`

Comment: @Paulw11 It didn't work, see my update in the question. I am wondering whether the exclamation point is causing the issues

Comment: @Paulw11 It did in fact work. It seems there is a cache on the Apple CDN side. 
If you could post this as answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything after # is not in the path. It is the fragment.

Apple shows an example of using the fragment in [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/supporting-associated-domains)

You will want something like

`"#":"!/courses/*/home"`

Apple will store your site association file in their CDN so it can take a number of days for changes to be seen by an app in production.

To avoid this causing problems while you are developing, you can add [`;mode=developer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains) to your domain entitlement and enable associated domains development in the *developer* menu on your device.

Comment: this worked for me. Now i can sleep in peace